# c++ Creating vector of function pointers in a given class, with function being a member of a different class

Tags: c++, vector, function-pointers, functor

I am having a vector of function pointers in one class and to it i want to pass address of function in some other class. The following implementation gives errors. What is the correct way?

```
class A
{
public:
 void func ()
 {
 }
};

class B
{
public:
 std::vector<void(*)()) myVec;
 void update_func()
 {
  myVec.push_back(&A::func);
 } 
};

int main()
{
 B* b = new B;
 b->update_func();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Paste the real code.  What you've posted has numerous typos and silly errors.

Comment: And post the full error as well.

Comment: `func()` is still private.  `myVec` is not declared properly.  Post the real code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd(v=vs.71).aspx) your error?

Comment: yes...i mentioned that error code itself...

Comment: @user1783299 Yes, but you can't expect us to know all error codes of the top of our heads. Next time, provide the full error message, not just its code. That way, it's clear what you're talking about, and we get additional information about the error (in this case, exactly what function and parameters the compiler complains about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer to the non-static member function `A::func` doesn't have type `void(*)(void)`, it has type `void(A::*)(void)`. So either change the vector to match the elements that you want it to have, or else use a pointer to a function of the correct type for the vector.

Comment: ok...thanks...any other way to do the push_back without making the member functions static?

Comment: @user1783299: not really. A non-static member function pointer must be called on an instance of the class `A`. A `void(*)(void)` can't provide that instance unless you store it in a global variable, or something similarly unsatisfactory. In C++11 you could look at `std::function` (for the element type of the vector) and `std::bind` (to get an instance of the element type that calls a specified member function on a specified object). In C++03 there are equivalents in Boost.

Comment: fine...cant i use myVec within func() and somehow pass the address of func() to myVec?

Comment: @user1783299: You can't store something of the wrong type in a vector. You might just as well be asking whether you can somehow store a `double` in a `vector<void(*)void>`, except that the type mismatch is slightly less easy to see in this case than the fact that `double` is different from a function pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

A's func() has to be static to match the declaration of the function pointer. Meanwhile, it needs to be `public` such that it is accessible to class B.
`update_func()` in B also needs to be public since otherwise in `main` it is not accessible.
vector declaration has typo, it has to be `vector<>`, not `vector<)`.

//

```
class A
{
  public:
   static void func ()
   {
   }
};

class B
{
 std::vector<void(*)()> myVec;
 public void update_func()
 {
  myVec.push_back(&A::func);
 } 
};

int main()
{
 B* b = new B;
 b->update_func();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has many issues..
first b->func should have () after it if you want to call that function..
second.. what is void update func().. also bad code..
third you cannot use these functions since they are private...
you do however push it correctly into the vector...

Comment: This is a valid comment to make, but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I am hoping I will have enough rep to comment soon... hmm

Comment: @JSQuareD: does that mean the code doesn't give the error that the questioner says it gives?

Comment: @JSQuareD: you'd know if you had the same compiler as the questioner -- C2664 is enough to identify the error (it's for the failed conversion), but I don't have MSVC on hand, so I don't know whether or not the questioner is still lying about this being the real code, and actually the other errors prevent this error being reported :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop He didn't even say what his compiler was... But yes, I assumed it was VS as well and googled the code. It indeed is a parameter conversion-error, and private functions would show a different error. So nope, still not his real code...